# Firestore: How can I force data synchronization when coming back online

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter app with cloud firestore and I am using the offline capabilities.
When coming back online after I made changes offline, it seems like the changes take quite some time to synchronise (sometime up to a minute).

Is there any ways to force the synchronisation manually so that I can could trigger it myself when listening for the device to get back online?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The native SDKs for iOS, Android, and Web have [API calls that allow you to explicitly manage connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access). While those are not explicitly made for your use-case, it'd be worth a try to see if disabling/re-enabling the network in short succession makes a difference.

Unfortunately those methods are currently not wrapped in the [`Firestore` class](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Firestore-class.html) of the FlutterFire library.

There is an open [issue in the Github repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21300) to track demand and progress on it. I just gave it an upvote.

Comment: I will give it a try ! Thank you for your answer